# Ohm's law in metals

Tags: condensed-matter, temperature, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

is [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) valid in metals at ALL temperatures or for a given temperature, it is always valid?

Where I am strugging is that for a given temperature, V-I could be linear with certain contant value of $R$, but if you change the temperature, resistance would change so for that temperature, again V-I would be linear but with different constant value of $R$?

Comment: Have you looked at this?  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/restmp.html

Comment: Related: [Can Ohm's law break in metals?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41067/can-ohms-law-break-in-metals)

Answer (score 4):

Ohm's law $V=IR$ can be traced to the relation $\mathbf{j}=\sigma \mathbf{E}$, that is, the current is linearly proportional to the applied electric field.

It is important to note that $R$ (or $\sigma$) depending on temperature, pressure,  humidity, time, etc. does not contradict Ohm's law. Said otherwise, linear response can hold true for different temperatures, pressures, etc.

What does contradict Ohm's law is a nonlinear dependence of the current on the voltage. This happens in many common circuit components. For example, diodes often obey $I = I_0e^{a V}$  instead of Ohm's law.  Transistors and other components have other even more complicated relationships.

The essential point here is that Ohm's law is that current is linearly proportional to the electric field. It is almost always valid for low enough electric field,  but how it breaks down depends on the system.

Comment: Why do you say that a resistance depending on temperature doesn't contradict Ohm's law? I think it does. As far as I know, Ohm's law states that current is directly proportional to voltage. That's true if the resistance is constant. If the resistance changes with temperature (which changes with current), then current is not directly proportional to voltage, so Ohm's law is violated. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Ohm's law says current through certain materials(including metals) is proportional to the voltage applied across it.Ofcourse the proportionality constant (R or 1/R ) changes with temperature for metals ,but current is still proportional to voltage so Ohm law is still valid.

Answer (score -1):

Ohm's law isn't actually correct, It describes an ideal resistor. In every day life, most metals are for a very good range of voltages and currents almost ideal resistors, but their resistance R depends on their temperature. Most of the time the resistance increases with temperature due to interactions of the electrons with phonons (vibrations of the atoms).

Moreover, you can use this phenomenon to calibrate a thermometer - apply a voltage to a certain metal and measure the current passing through it. Then, calculate the resistance and from that you can conclude the temperature! Voila, you just made yourself a [resistance thermometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_thermometer).

Comment: This is a very misleading answer. Ohm's law in the general context does not make the statement that $R$ is fixed for all environmental parameters. Instead it merely states that $R$ does not depend on the voltage (or electric field).

Comment: I didn't say that what Ohm's law states, only that metals don't really have a linear IV curve

Comment: You said "Ohm's law isn't actually correct, It describes an ideal resistor" which is false

Comment: @KFGauss When you say Ohm's law is correct, how do you define "Ohm's law"?

Comment: see my answer. At the most simplistic level Ohm's law says the relation between current and voltage is linear (slope is the resistance), and has nothing to do with temperature, pressure, etc.